# How can I select an audio output device in directshow

Tags: audio

I was wondering how I can select the output device for audio in directshow. I am able to get available audio output devices in directshow. But how can I make one of these to be audio output device. Its always going for the default audio device. I want to be able to output audio on my choice of device. I have been struggling through google but couldn't find anything useful. All I could get was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Any help will be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it, but a quick MSDN browsing makes me think you could try that:

1. Enumerate the available devices using an `IMMDeviceEnumerator`, and let your user pick one. You should have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a head start.
2. Use the `GUID` of the selected device for your call to `DirectSoundCreate`. [Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundcreate8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to do but I'm guessing you want to do something like change the output device from speakers to headphones or something? I don't believe that you can change the output device via code and I think that is something that can only be changed in the playback devices in the windows sound and volume control.

Comment: Mungoid, Thanks for reply. Ya I am trying to do something similar, To clarify further, Suppose we have two or more sound cards on system, and I want to be able to play audio on any of those cards by user's choice. I can enumerate through devices available on system, but I am not able to play audio on selected device. how can I do that?